# How to organize a large ASP.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a quite large ASP.NET project to work on, the front-end part(design).The code for it is allready written but given it has 80+ web pages I need to organize the files a bit so I can ease my work.
What would be some general pointers in organizing a allready written ASP.NET project?

P.S
The project has like 2 folders tops, everything else is in the main project folder.

Comment: Put stuff in folders in a meaningful way.

Comment: Try adding folders for modules, settings, common, etc. I am not sure if that breaks any links/paths already written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each application organization will depend on its complexity and business purpose being achieved. However, the more you are able to segregate functionality, the more manageable it will be for you.

Divide the functionality into *business* vs *infrastructure*.

The business one will get classified into different modules per workflow type involved. The infrastructure one will get classified into functional blocks like logging, security, database. There will be one *admin* section to manage users, map roles and permissions, check access logs etc.